# Why isn't this formula working?

Tags: excel

Can somebody tell me why the second IF statement isn't working in the below code?

I basically require 3 things to happen;

1. If there is a value in D,E,F,G,H then i want it to type with ","
   "and" like this; blueberries, cranberries, black currents,
   strawberries and gojiberries
2. If there is a value in only D,E,F,G then; blueberries, cranberries, black currents and strawberries
3. If there is a value in only D,E,F then; blueberries, cranberries and black currents

I can only get two of the statements to work...

=IF(H8=0,(D8)&", "&(E8)&", "&(F8)&" and "&(G8),(IF(G8=0,(D8)&", "&(E8)&" and "&(F8),(D8)&", "&(E8)&", "&(F8)&", "&(G8)&" and "&(H8))))

My rows looks like this: 
D=blueberries   E=cranberries   F=black currents    G=strawberries  H=gojiberries

Please help

Alex

Answer (score 3):

This will only return the concatenation of cell values that are not blank, with commas between values unless the next cell is blank, in which case the comma is replaced with `" and "`.

`=D8&IF(E8<>"",IF(F8<>"",", "," and "),)&E8&IF(F8<>"",IF(G8<>"",", "," and "),)&F8&IF(G8<>"",IF(H8<>"",", "," and "),)&G8&IF(H8<>""," and "&H8,"")`

Comment: I took the liberty of adjusting your formatting to avoid wrapping & duplicating the formula. You can view the edit history to see how.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this version

`=D8&", "&E8&", "&F8&IF(G8=0,"",", "&G8)&IF(H8=0,"",", "&H8)`

Comment: You still need to substitute the last comma with the word 'and' like this: `=SUBSTITUTE(D1&", "&E1&", "&F1&IF(G1=0,"",", "&G1)&IF(H1=0,"",", "&H1),","," and",(COUNTA(D1:H1)-1))`

Comment: True, I missed the "and" part....but Mark Fitzgerald's answer is better if you want to include the possibility of 0 1 or 2 entries